# Counting Values in a repeated field in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select rows that have more thank k values in a repeated field. (consider for example selecting user that have more than 3 email addresses)

In Standard SQL I know I can use

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.users
WHERE array_length(email_address) > 3
```

But what is the way to do this in BigQuery legacy SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for a subquery; you should be able to filter with `OMIT RECORD IF` directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset.users
OMIT RECORD IF COUNT(email_address) <= 3;
```

Do you mind commenting on why you want to use legacy SQL, though? If you encountered a problem with standard SQL I'd like to understand what it was so that we can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: No I have not experienced any problem with Standard SQL, It is just because this is part of a query in my system that is already written in legacy SQL and converting the whole query to standard SQL is not completely straight forward.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> Counting Values in a repeated field in BigQuery

BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(email_address) WITHIN RECORD AS address_count
FROM [dataset.users]
```

If you want then to count output rows - you can use below

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS rows_count 
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(email_address) WITHIN RECORD AS address_count
  FROM [dataset.users]
)
WHERE address_count> 3
```